# getting Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority eventhough already granted Domain-Wide Delegation

Tags: google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

I'm using a service account to create calendar entries and adding new attendees
for creating new appointments there is no problem

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%7Bin_creator%7D/events
```

When adding new attendees, I get the error:

> "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority".

for adding new invitees I use:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%7BOwner%7D/events/%7Bmeeting_id%7D
```

All the information in the body of the call (including the list of attendees)
({Owner} is the real owner the calendar, it's not the service account)

I'm the Google Workspace admin, so I already granted scopes in the Domain-wide Delegation screen to this service account:

- https://googleapis.com/auth/calendar,
- https://googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
- [https://googleapis.com/auth/admin.director`](https://googleapis.com/auth/admin.director%60)

the owner of the calendar granted "`Make Changes Event`" permission to the service account

the JWT for request the access token looks like:

```
{
  "iss": "xxxxxx.gserviceaccount.com",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar",
  "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "exp": "{exp}",
  "iat": "{iat}"
}
```

I've tried calling the apis using  Oracle PLSQL / Apexx using

```
apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
  p_url => t_url, 
  p_http_method => 'POST', 
  p_body => t_json_in, 
  p_parm_name => apex_util.string_to_table(
    'conferenceDataVersion:supportsAttachments:maxAttendees:sendNotifications:sendUpdates'
  ), 
  p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table('1:True:12:False:False')
);
where 
  t_url : variable cointaining the target endpoint : xxxx googleapis.com / calendar / v3 / calendars / {Owner} / events / {meeting_id} which returns a CLOB containing a JSON t_json_in : variable with a JSON with all the event data
```

this function returns a CLOB with a JSON

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "calendar",
        "reason": "forbiddenForServiceAccounts",
        "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."
  }
}
```

Comment: I would love to see the code you are using to create the JWT for the authorization request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For delegation the JWT for the access token request needs to include the Sub claim. [see: service-account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

> sub    The email address of the user for which the application is requesting delegated access.

This is the email address of the owner of the account for which delegation has been configured.  The service account it self may have read access but to have write access it needs to be deligated.

```
{
  "iss": "xxxxxx.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub": "owner@yourdomain.com"
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar",
  "aud": "xxxx oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "exp": "{exp}",
  "iat": "{iat}"
}
```

Comment: Seriously tell me how  you are making that jwt token.  I have been trying to get the signature to work for ages.  I cant get it to authorize.

Comment: Hi, I try to copy the code here but it was too long. is there any other way to share it with you :-/ (i'm new to stacloverflow shame on me)

Comment: check my profile I have a number of contact methods.